# Woocommerce custom checkout page per product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce product which requires different fields than the others.
Is there a way to have a custom checkout page specifically for this product?

Comment: Yes you can specify the checkout page for a specific product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have custom checkout page for specific product. However, you can customize checkout fields dynamically based on product in your cart.

---

```
// Override fields like this
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'My new placeholder';
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'My new label';
     return $fields;
}

// Remove fields like this
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);

     return $fields;
}
```

You can find more details on how to customize woocommerce checkout fields here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Comment: How ? can you please specify ? @vidish

Comment: added piece of code

Comment: is it possible to add fields?

Comment: Yes, you can add custom fields. Refer to this code : https://gist.github.com/hannahswain/681ad5431d85125a1c54510ee084645d#file-custom-shipping-and-billing